# What does "a = b != -1" mean?

Tags: python

I'm a Python beginner, and trying to improve my skill.

Recently I read the source cord of some python packages, and found these codes.

```
while True:
    x = string_variable != -1
    if x:
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        break
```

So, what does the second line mean?

You can find the original cord in 149th line of `__init__.py` from [here](https://github.com/linouk23/youtube_uploader_selenium).

The original cord is below.

```
status_container = self.browser.find(By.XPATH,
                                         Constant.STATUS_CONTAINER)
while True:
    in_process = status_container.text.find(Constant.UPLOADED) != -1
    if in_process:
        time.sleep(Constant.USER_WAITING_TIME)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Look at it as `x = (string_variable != -1)` and it should hopefully become clearer.

Comment: put into `a` whether `b` equals `-1`. Meaning: if `b` is `-1` then put `False` else put `True`

Comment: Just to add here, the code you are looking at is not a string variable. `string_var.find("thing") != -1` is looking for an occurrance of "thing" inside the string_var.

Comment: ```x = string_variable != -1```, ```!=``` is for comparison and returning True or False, and then it is checking ```if x``` or ```if True```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add here, the actual code you are looking at is not a simple string variable test like your example:

```
in_process = status_container.text.find(Constant.UPLOADED) != -1
```

is effectively doing this:

```
string_var.find("foo") != -1
```

which is looking for an occurrence of "foo" inside the string_var. The string.find() function returns the index of the substring inside the string. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp

So `if string_var.find("foo") != -1:` is basically saying "if foo is in string_var".

A more common (and readable!) way to do this in python is simply:

```
if "foo" in string_var:
```

Answer (score 1):

This line has two operators

```
x = string_variable != -1
```

`=` is assignment operator and `!=` is logical operator which means `NOT EQUALS`

so, `x` will hold a boolean value based on the evaluation of the logical operator `!=`.